# Docker multiple ipaddress

Tags: docker

I have couple of containers running

```
vagrant@nav:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3401574617ea        j/ros-tutorials:latest   "/tini -- /ros_ent..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        rosdemo_master.1.yled0m2ygtoha1gs09mrvwho5
dd1a5a4ed5b2        j/ros-tutorials:latest   "/tini -- /ros_ent..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        rosdemo_listener.1.fjv2u7yxihxvzkfzmomhnq9
```

but when I try to get their ipaddress using the below script -

```
for i in $(sudo docker ps -q); do sudo docker inspect $i| grep IPA; done
```

I get the following output -

```
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "IPAddress": "",
                "IPAMConfig": {
                "IPAddress": "10.255.0.5",
                "IPAMConfig": {
                "IPAddress": "10.2.0.7",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "IPAddress": "",
                "IPAMConfig": {
                "IPAddress": "10.2.0.9",
```

wondering why I get 3 ipaddresses -

```
10.255.0.5
10.2.0.7
10.2.0.9
```

Comment: How did you start these docker containers? one by one or with compose?

Comment: I'm using docker swarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containers are attached to multiple Docker networks.

Don't use `grep` to extract the IP Addresses, This is all structured data and Docker supports go template formatting out of the box.

To get the main IP Address:

```
docker inspect $CID \
  -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}'
```

The get any IP Addresses assigned to networks:

```
docker inspect $CID \
  -f '{{ range .NetworkSettings.Networks }}{{ .IPAddress }}{{ end }}'
```

To print the network name along with the IP:

```
docker inspect $CID \
  -f '{{ range $k,$v :=.NetworkSettings.Networks }}{{$k}} {{.IPAddress}}{{ end }}'
```